# What is real time indicator?

Tags: meaning, phrases, prepositions

Does 'real time indicator' mean collecting data:
-over time at specific period, for example of the year/month etc, or
-as it happens, for example, in very short intervals, like a month, week, day or hours?
Below is original body of text:

'Given the highly-fluid situation, the Ministry of Trade and Industry (MTI) is tapping on high-frequency and real-time indicators, in addition to traditional indicators, to monitor the latest economic developments and assess the impact of COVID-19 on the Singapore economy. Apart from monitoring the real-time economic indicators that have been developed in-house, MTI has also worked with public and private sector partners to obtain new sources of non-traditional high- frequency data such as daily data on credit card spending, online food orders and electricity consumption, which can provide an indication of the health of different aspects of the Singapore economy on a more timely basis'.

Comment: Real-time indicator is an indicator that is based on real-time data, that is present time data. It contrasts with the more common methodology of collecting data on historical basis (referring to past moth, year etc.)

Comment: My guess is that traditional indicators, like a moving-average, say, are more accurate forecasters than simply taking the latest figures and guessing the trend. This is not everyday English. Really you need to research the subject to discover what the traditional indicators are.

Comment: *Real-time* is [in dictionaries](https://www.lexico.com/definition/real_time): the definition in Lexico says data is collected within **milliseconds,** as it happens. Please do look things up.

Answer (score 2):

Real time indicators are events happening in the present, not in a week or a day. They are counted or summed as they occur.